# Spring OAuth2 Separate Authorization Token Server and Authentication Server

Tags: spring, authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization

I am aiming to have the following structure:

1. The UI
2. The Resource Server
3. The **Authorization** Server
4. The **Authentication** Server

I want the **Authorization** and **Authentication** to be done by two separate entities, each running in their own container.
Basically, I want to achieve the same thing as in [here](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/) in the end, like Facebook and GIT, to use the authentication from my dedicated server in order to generate tokens with the authorization server that the UI will use to get the resource from the Resource Server.

I tried and I was able to follow the example in the above link to forward the request to authenticate to the other container, but there I get stuck. I can't seem to find any place on the web to explain how the authentication server should reply back to the authorization server.

Any idea on how to achieve this?